# Close AngularStrap Modal on some event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStrap with bootstrap.
I have `serverErrorInterceptor` service, where I handle all my server errors.
I want implement following logic of server error handling:

1. close currently opened modal (from AngularStrap) window, if any.
2. open new modal window with error description.

AngularStrap provide 2 ways to close modal window:

1. via method on modal instance: `modal.hide()`;
2. via method, defined on modal scope: `modal.$scope.$hide()`

Obviously there is only first method is suitable for my case.
But the problem is that I has no idea about how I can get access to currently opened modal window instance - it was instantiated outside of `serverErrorInterceptor`.

So my question is how I can get access to currently opened modal window instance from `serverErrorInterceptor` (to be able to close it) or may be there is a third method to close modal window?

Comment: please add sample of your modal and little code create plunker sir

Comment: I've provided more detailed description of the problem. The problem is general so I don't what code sample will be helpful in this case.